# How to add <li> on pressing "Enter" in input tab of Todo list using only DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var listLis=document.getElementById('list');
const addbutton=document.querySelector('.fa-plus')
const inputBar=document.querySelector('.show')


function showInput(e){
    inputBar.classList.toggle('show')
}

addbutton.addEventListener('click',showInput);
document.getElementById('myText').value='';
inputBar.addEventListener('keypress',seeToIt);

function seeToIt(e){

    var textInInput= document.getElementById('myText').value;
    var linode=document.createElement('li');
    if(e.code=='Enter'){
        linode.appendChild("Fpru");
        listLis.appendChild(linode)
        textInInput='';
    }
}
```

This is the code.For JS. HTML code is-

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>To-Do List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" id='myText' class="show"placeholder="Add New To-Do">
    <ul id='list'>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I am not able to add the to do item to my ul.
'list' is the id for ul. I am confused that on keypress on input tab I should fire up the event which will store the li on pressing enter key.

Comment: are you focusing the `inputBar` before pressing the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work right now?

```js
var listLis=document.getElementById('list');
const addbutton=document.querySelector('.fa-plus')
const inputBar=document.querySelector('.show')
const delAll = document.querySelector('.deleteAll')



function showInput(e){
    inputBar.classList.toggle('show')
}

addbutton.addEventListener('click',showInput);
document.getElementById('myText').value='';
inputBar.addEventListener('keypress',seeToIt);

delAll.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ listLis.innerHTML = ''})


function seeToIt(e){
    var textInInput= document.getElementById('myText');
    var linode = document.createElement('li');
    if(e.code=='Enter'){
        linode.innerHTML = `${textInInput.value}<button class='del' onclick="this.parentNode.remove()"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></i></i></button>`
        listLis.appendChild(linode)
        textInInput.value='';
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css"
<div id="container">
    <h1>To-Do List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" id='myText' class="show"placeholder="Add New To-Do">
    <button class='deleteAll'><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    <ul id='list' >

    </ul>
    
</div>
```

Comment: NumPad ENTER does not trigger event

Comment: @RobMoll you need to look for the keycode : `if (e.keyCode == 13 )` instead code `if (e.code == "Enter" )`. Look at https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes for more keycodes

Comment: @RobMoll my Enter work nice. I am just fixing some author mistakes. That not my code.

Comment: @RobMoll demo working on NumPad Enter key : https://jsfiddle.net/qrxmgfzj/

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I feel so stupid now when I see the issue.

Comment: @DimaVak Any idea how I can add a font awesome trash can to the left of the list so that the user can delete the list?

Comment: @DivyamMadhok 1 button delete all? Or many button, and they delete item nearby

Comment: @DimaVak all li will have the font awesome button next to them so that when user press it, it will individually delete that particular li. Many button, that delete item nearby.

Comment: @DivyamMadhok check my snippet. I rewrote it

Comment: @DimaVak Thanks you're a life saver. One last thing how can I add trash in front of each "<li>" so that we can delete one at a time?